# Display dataframe with string formatting

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I am sending a mail with boto3 and write the body of the mail with string formatting. However, when I add my dataframe in string formatting, the shape of the frame corrupts.
I need to use string formatting to achieve this. Added an image to show how the rows and columns shift, when I add the dataframe to string formatting. How can I add the dataframe so that the rows and columns are aligned and they do not shift like shown in the image? Note that the dataframe is an example and not the actual one. I need a solution without manual intervention. The code of the dataframe and string formatting is provided below.

```py
import pandas as pd
example_df = pd.DataFrame({"Counts":[10,20,30,40], "Percentages": [12,15,16,167]},index = ["ok", "eliminated due to no sales", "eliminated due to low score", "eliminated due to late submission"])

"The dataframe has {} rows and {} columns.\n Dataframe is as follows: \n {}".format(example_df.shape[0], example_df.shape[1], example_df)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MeatBALL I'm using python 3

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong. I'm not sure I can help.